# Optimize nested loops for counting the total number of selections

Tags: c++, complexity

The question is: To select 2 numbers out of n positive integer inputs (order matters), where the number that is placed anywhere before the second must be greater than the second by a given number m. Count the total number of selections.

An example answer would be, given the inputs 5 1 3 2 4 and m is 0, the total number of selections is 5 (51,53,52,54,32)

Another example answer would be, given the inputs 6 5 4 3 2 1 and m is 2, the total number of selections is 6 (63,62,61,52,51,41)

How do I improve my double for-loop method in terms of time?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j, m = 0, sum = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int *a=new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
        
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if (a[i] - m <= 0)  continue;
        int temp=a[i]-m;
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        if(a[j]<temp) sum++;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: Think of counting inversions. The approach is the same, with a slight modification.

Comment: The results of your second example seems to be missing 64, 53, 42 and 31

Comment: No, it has to be strictly greater than 2.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Don't do this.  We have namespaces for a reason, you know.  And we seem to be missing the necessary Standard Library headers `<iostream>` and `<cstdio>`.

> ```
>     int n, m, i, j, m = 0, sum = 0;
> ```

These variable names tell us nothing about what they are used for.  Please use more expressive names.

> ```
>     cin >> n >> m;
> ```

When reading from a stream such as `std::cin`, it's vital to check that the conversion was successful before using the values.  That could be as simple as

```
if (!cin) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

> ```
>     int *a=new int[n];
> ```

Prefer a standard container (e.g. `std::vector`).

> ```
>     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
> ```

If we had a `std::vector`, we could have avoided hand-coding this loop:

```
auto a = std::vector{};
a.reserve(n);
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), n, a.begin());
```

> ```
>         scanf("%d", &a[i]);
> ```

Why are we mixing C++ streams and C stdio?  It's better to use just one (preferably the streams).  Again, we're missing the test whether the conversion was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vnp's comment about counting inversions! This link should be fully sufficient to optimize your code with a modified merge sort scheme:

https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-algorithms-counting-inversions-71aaa579a2c0

As far as I can see, the only thing you'll have to modify is this line

```
if array[i] > array[j]
```

with your desired delta value m.